# Как убрать рамку в combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Как убрать рамку чтобы осталась только стрелка ▼ ? И необходимо сделать стрелку белой. Пробую таким образом

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" Width="16" Height="20" Margin="570,10,10,670" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}"  Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="True">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Свернуть"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Закрыть"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

Но это проблемы не решает. Всем заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

Нажмите правой кнопкой на Combobox в визуальном редакторе, выберите `Правка шаблона - Правка копии`. В ваш xaml добавится огромный стиль, где есть всё. Например, стрелка:

```
<Path x:Name="Arrow"
        Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"
        Fill="Black"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="3,1,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Меняйте `Fill` на `White`.

Для рамки найдите

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
        RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
```

Меняйте `BorderBrush` на `{x:Null}`.

Конечно этот стиль потом желательно вынести в другой файл.

Comment: Цвет изменил, получилось. Пытаюсь убрать рамку - не получается, хотя делаю как вы говорите "Меняйте BorderBrush на {x:Null}."

Comment: @YuriGo Обновил немного. Ищите самое первое вхождение, у меня все получилось.

Comment: изменил и так и там, тоненькая рамка все также осталась

Comment: @YuriGo Сделайте небольшое исследование. Введите в поиск `BorderBrush`, и меняйте все в подряд. Если не влияет на результат - отменяйте.

Comment: Результат, почему то, ни к чему не приводит...Не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: @YuriGo попробуйте еще Background поправить